# C#: how to exit from a method when a event called

Tags: c#, multithreading, smpp

i have an attaching event like:

```
mySmppClient.evDeliver_Sm += new SmppClient.Deliver_SmEventHandler(mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm);

mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm(){
// have some code here.
}
```

and another method like: `check_outbox();`

application is always check the `check_outbox()` method.

Now if the code debugging pointer into the  `check_outbox()` method and at the same time the event fire then application get hang.Because it start working for `mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm()`.

My question is : If the event fire then the check_outbox complete it's current task and then it will call the `mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm()`.

is it possible? or have any other way to do it?or may i synchronize the scenario?

Comment: Can you please show the relevant code that goes along with what issues you are reporting..?

Comment: i have the below two line like: mySmppClient.evDeliver_Sm += new SmppClient.Deliver_SmEventHandler(mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm);
                        check_outbox();  now my application always go through those method. check_outbox alwayes checkin into a database for new entry and send a SMS to user when find.check_outbox is nothing but holding some database query.But problem is, when the event fire the application hang.because it's pointer goes to the mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm() method.

Comment: `check_outbox()` where is the method..?

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable (named KeepRunning for instance) that is shared between threads.  Loop inside your method, check the boolean variable periodically, and exit the method if it is false.  In the controlling thread, set the boolean variable to false when you want the method to exit.

Comment: Note that there are synchronization issues here in which a stale value can be read.  I'd highly suggest using `CancellationToken` instead of just a boolean.  Under the hood it's not much more than a wrapper around that boolean, but it will take care of synchronization on your behalf.

Answer (score -1):

you should maybe run `mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm()` in a new thread and you can abort it whenever you want.